# empty array attribute on php object

Tags: php

This is my class,which reads a csv and store the info in some way

```
<?php
    class CSV{
        private $data;

        function __construct($filename){
            $this->data = $this->getDataFromFile($filename);
        }

        public function __get($property){

            if(property_exists($this,$property)){
                return $this->$property;
            }
        }



        private function getDataFromFile($filename){
            $new_data = array();
            $result = array();
            if (($handle = fopen($filename,"r")) !== FALSE) {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    array_push($result, explode(";", $data[0]));;
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }


            $header = $result[0];

            $in_columns = array();
            for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($result[0]); $j++){
                $new = array();
                for ($i = 1 ; $i < count($result); $i++){
                    array_push($new, $result[$i][$j]);
                }
                array_push($in_columns, $new);
            }

            $idx = 0;
            foreach ($header as $title) {
                $new_data[$title] = $in_columns[$idx];
                $idx++; 
            }
            //var_dump($new_data);//the content of $new_data its correct
            $this->data = $new_data;
        }
    }

?>
```

but wen I try to use the class

```
$csv = new CSV('./csv/file.csv');
var_dump($csv->__get('data'));
```

the last var_dump shows a NULL value ¿What is wrong on the assignation of the value?It looks correct for me ,where cold be the problem??

Comment: Why don't you try instead of `$this->data = $this->getDataFromFile($filename);` set something simply to test is it populated correctly like `$this->data = array('test1', 'test2');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're calling `$this->getDataFromFile($filename)` in constructor and assigning it's value to `$this->data`.
 However... implementation of `getDataFromFile()` didn't actually return any value, so it's assigning `NULL` to this property.

You need to change `getDataFromFile()` to return value **OR**
 get rid of variable assignment in constructor -
 `$this->data` is already set in your method.

Regarding `__get()` -
 it's a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). It checks if specified property exists and if so - return it's value. You won't call it this way. Use following code (after making `$this->data` public):

```
var_dump($csv->data);
```

**OR** prepare accessor for this property which will return this value.

Comment: But  `$csv->data` it's private

Comment: Then prepare an accessor like `getData()` where you'll return this property or make it public.

Comment: Same result with `getData()`

Comment: Actually... wait. In constructor you're calling `$this->getDataFromFile($filename)` and assigning it's value to `$this->data`. However... your implementation of `getDataFromFile` didn't return any value at all, so it's assigning NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your CSV file ends with a blank line (`\n` after the last line).

Thus you're working on an empty array, pushing an unitialized variable (null) into the data array.